# How to toggle an elements state in Safari web inspector?

Tags: ios, css, safari

I'm trying to debug a site by plugging in my iPad and using the Safari developer tools to see what is going on. The problem is that it appears when an elements background colour changes in the 'focus' state. As this is only for a split second I can't see what CSS rule is responsible

With Chrome there is an option to toggle the state on an element, is there one for the Safari inspector?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this isn't possible as of now, but it'll be available soon based on what's shown here:

https://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/whats-new.html#inspector

**Edit**: I'm on Safari 9.1.3 now, and it looks like this is now available:

[image: Toggling pseudo-classes in Safari 9.1.3]